# How to Run the Unit Test As the part of Build (Not continuous integration)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nunit, msbuild-task

I have Nunit unit test which i need to run as the part of my MS build.. I know that running all the test will slow up the build So, i need to run only the impacted test is there any way to find that out..

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK running only impacted tests is not possible yet for NUnit tests. But this is possible for MSTests in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate/Test Professional:

[Recommending Tests to Run That are Affected by Code Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286589.aspx)

> You can use Visual Studio Ultimate  or Visual Studio Test Professional
>   2010 to help you determine which tests might have to be run, based on
>   coding changes that were made to the application you are testing. To
>   be able to use this functionality, you have to use Team Foundation
>   Build to build your application and use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
>   for version control for your source code

Anyway you can use [MSBuild Community NUnit Task](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) to run tests from a set of the assemblies. You can do this as dependency target of standard `AfterBuild` target by specifying `DependsOnTargets` attribute.

```xml
<NUnit Assemblies="..."
       IncludeCategory="..."
       ExcludeCategory="..."
       ToolPath="$(NUnitDllsPath)"
       ProjectConfiguration="$(Configuration)"
       OutputXmlFile="$(NUnitOutputPath)\UnitTests.xml"
       ContinueOnError="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the impacted tests you need to track the test case code coverage. Only this way you can examine what test is impacted by the changes you are checking in. I don't know of any tool that does what you want besides Microsofts Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 0):

Running your tests as a part of the build can be done trough the Build Events properties of your project. You can execute the command line tool for NUnit.

But as PVitt already pointed out, I don't know if NUnit can work with Test Impact analysis.